# Run method within a method without completion

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

So I have two methods

```
-(void)someMethod
{
    [self someOtherMethod];
    //Do some other stuff
}

-(void)someOtherMethod
{
    //Do some other stuff
}
```

And I was wondering if it is possible to run someOtherMethod as shown in the code above, but without waiting for someOtherMethod to finish running before continuing on.

Answer (score 4):

```
dispatch_async(... some queue ..., ^{
    [self someOtherMethod];
});
```

Note that you can use one of the global concurrent queues, but you need to be careful to not pound on it or you'll end up with dozens of threads.  You may want to create your own concurrent serial queue and enqueue there.